# How ES6 classes compiled?

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-class

While I was looking to react native animations documentation, I read something interesting to me. Code piece:

```
class FadeInView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
  }

  // Other parts of code piece ...
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html
}
```

> Let's break down what's happening here. In the FadeInView constructor, a new Animated.Value called fadeAnim is initialized as part of state.

In the above statement docs mentioning that state is initialized in constructor. However there is no constructor in this code piece. From the knowledge of other languages like c# and c++ etc. variables can be declared and initialized in classes without constructor.

1. I actually didn't understand underlying process in javascript how these variables declared and initialized in es6 classes.
2. Why he is mentioning constructor while there isn't any constructor.
3. How es6 classes compiled? (This might be long, overall picture of that can be enough for my needs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` is a class property, currently not an ES6+ standard feature. 
Therefore you need the Babel `Stage 2 preset` in order to [transform class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Currently, that plugin transformation moves the class properties into the constructor. Check the babel [repl output](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiYBMCmBJAdgNQJZIO7QG8AoaaCAFzHKWgF5CTToAzRJAQTSwFsAuaNHmiceVJAgB0GMCACuSABQAGAJQAaUgHpN0dFnJYZ0AG4z5LAPYAnaBYAOYYPoCe_JYwC-RL0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Simplified Babel output:

> ```
> function FadeInView() {    
>   this.state = {
>     fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0) // Initial value for opacity: 0
>   };
> };
> ```

More info related to [class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Class properties (a [js proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/README.md) yet) are actually moved into the constructor:

```
  class FadeInView extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
    this.state = {
      fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for  
      opacity : 0
    };
   }
 }
```

Comment: class Foo {
 this.bar = 0
 constructor(paramBar){
  this.bar = paramBar
 } 
}

So what if I call : new Foo(2)

Comment: @batu g. The property will be moved into the beginning of the constructor.